# Entering the text in TinyMCE through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have embedded the TinyMCE in WebBrowser control and using it as a HTML WYSIWYG editor in my WPF app.

On the html page containing TinyMCE, I have:

```
function getContent() {
 return tinyMCE.get('elm1').getContent();
}
```

I am calling this function on the WPF Button click as follows to obtain the content of TinyMCE in C#:

```
 string editHtml = this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("getContent").ToString();
```

However I want to set the content of the TinyMCE from the file before it loads, just to show text previously entered by the user, so that he/she can continue to modify the older content, instead writing the new content. How can I set the content of the TinyMCE through C#.

Thank you.

Comment: are you saving the data in database?

Comment: @Rocky - possibly not, but what difference it will make? May be I will stream the content to the txt file and then load it from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the data in database then on edit, select the data from table, and assign the text to your text box..

```
txbItemText.Text = ListofItems[0].description;
```

Comment: Thanks @Rocky for your response and sorry for my late response. I want to clear the fact that the control will be on the html page, I am loading that page in WPF WebBrowser control, and on click of button on the WPF form (not in the html page), I have following line of code                                                                   'string editHtml = this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("getContent").ToString();'              which will allow accessing the text entered by the user in tinyMce in WPF app. So here I dont have tinymce on aspx page to write your line in code behind.